# install xcode 4.1 for lion in vmware

Tags: xcode4, osx-lion, vmware-fusion

I installed Lion in a vmware (using vmware fusion).
I downloaded the xcode 4.1 for lion and trying to install it on the VM.
It does not work. The installer just keeps runnning, seems like an infinite loop.

I tried different things suggested on different forums.
But nothing has worked so far.

Comment: How long have you let it run?

Comment: around 20 mins.
the progress bar did not show any progress.

Comment: In the future, please post any output from the problem app in your console log. Run /Applications/Utilities/Console.app and select the All Messages group if it isn't already. This should be your *first stop* when an app looks to be misbehaving outside a debugger console.